# Running periodic build job in Jenkins in the interval of 1 hour between completion of previous build and start of next build

Tags: jenkins

I have one Jenkins build job which run periodically every hour.
I want know is there any way where i can configure my Jenkins build in such a way that my next build starts 1 hour after the completion of previous build

Comment: Well, when your job lasts 5 minutes, you could plan your next build 1 hour and 5 minutes after the start of your job - but that is all you can do...

Comment: @mylenereiners My job completion time is not fixed ,it varies .Sometime its take say 5 minutes and next time 15 mins

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quiet period feature](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/quiet-period-feature) to do this.

Configure your job with your custom time period ( 3600s ), and trigger the job when you build finish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but the quite period configuration is at jenkins  level,i want it at a particular job level ,i do not want to it to affect other jobs.

Comment: No. You can configure  for your jobs, with different configurations. Select your job -> configure -> Advanced Project Options -> Quiet Period. Profit.